# I am glad to be selected vs. I am glad to have been selected

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

When someone makes a speech about having been selected as an outstanding employee of the month, which is correct to say between "I am glad to be selected" and "I am glad to have been selected"? Thank you.

Comment: I am glad to be selected suggests it is happening **right now**, as we speak.

Comment: *I'm glad to be selected* = *I'm glad that I'm selected*; *I'm glad to have been selected* = *I'm glad that I've been selected*.

Comment: @Lambie: Not necessarily.  It is if you look at selection as an instantaneous event, but it is equally valid to look at it as a status change.  The speaker's status was "candidate"; now his status is "selected", and it is his status in the present time even though the selection activities are long past.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Ben.  It all depends on the context.

Comment: @BenVoigt If the question is asked **the day after the selection is made**, you simply would not say: I am glad to be selected. You really would say, the following day: I am glad to have been selected. Of course, people don't seem to "GAS" about register or level of language and apparently everything goes.

Comment: @Lambie: Absolutely one can say "I am selected" and "I am glad to be selected" a day, or multiple days, after the selection is made.  When the selection is made, it grants the status "selected".  That status is ongoing, and can be spoken of in the present tense.  Consider: *That apartment building was burned last month by a kitchen fire.  Now it is a burned out shell.*  The same ambiguity applies here.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I'm glad to be selected [by x almost every year to do some x  to be some x]. or: I am selected at this point. Those two are general statements using a passive form for a general statement.  BUT: I'm glad to have been selected this year, too. I'm glad to be selected [by x]=X selects me [every year, usually, etc.]

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is the **active voice in the simple present**:

I'm glad that **my fellow students select me** to be the class clown almost every year.

**The simple present is used for general statements like the one above**.

**Passive voice of the same sentences in the present simple**:

I'm glad I **am selected by my fellow students** to be class clown almost every year.

**The same exact meaning is conveyed by**:

I'm glad to be selected by my fellow students almost every year.

The use of **to be selected** here is the same as: **am selected by** And, it refers to a general statement. It is also a passive.

Otherwise, the tense has to change: I'm glad/was glad I was selected by x to be y.

If you want to refer to being selected at a past time, it would be thus:

I'm glad to have been selected by x to be y.

Conclusion: **to be selected is the passive voice of the present tense** and has to refer to a general statement. It's logical idea is a general statement.

I'm happy to be selected [by all of you]. **General statement** referring to the fact of selection and in the present time or near future. It is not a past tense idea.

I'm happy you **selected me** today for this job. [the selecting was done at some point earlier in the day].

I'm happy to **have been selected** [by all of you] for this job [earlier today or in the past when the specific time of selection is not given or relevant].

It is equivalent in meaning to: I'm happy you **have selected me** for the job**.

Answer (score 0):

*"I am glad to be selected"* suggests that you were selected very recently. You could say that right after being selected, e.g. during your speech.

If you wanted to emphasize that you were selected in the past, you'd say *"I am glad to have been selected"*.

Comment: Misses the point that *I ... (to be, present) selected* is more likely a statement of status than a passive voice construction.

Comment: It would be nice if it were that simple, but it is not.  In some contexts the past perfect sounds more *polite*, or at least more *genteel*, but otherwise either one gives no information about the time frame.